# Scan an APK to list out localizations

Tags: android

Is there a way to scan an APK and list out the supported localizations? The android market shows these when uploading the application to the store; however, I would like the QA department to be able to verify these localizations prior to submission.

According to the Android documentation, it appears that you have to know that a localization is supported before you can test for that localization.  I'd like to find a way to ask the APK what it supports to drive the localization testing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a resource xml file that contains the languages that the app supports. Then in your testapp you can do

```
Context otherAppContext = getApplicatoinContext().createPackageContext("com.android.app1", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);  
Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(otherAppContext.getResources(),com.android.app1.R.drawable.pic);
```

The above code gets a bitmap from the apk. You can modify it to get the xml file from raw folder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'd like to ask the SDK what localization it thinks the application supports... If I have to rely on a developer populating an XML file than this approach will not add any additional risk mitigation.